# Function does not return any value if called in a class

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I am trying to make my version of Zork & Adventures from the tutorial I found [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html)

This tutorial uses an Engine class that from a Map class select what scene must come next and so on.
To select the next scene, the Engine takes the return value of a function and select the scene to play.

from sys import exit
from random import randint

```
class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."
        exit(1)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        # be sure to print out the last scene
        current_scene.enter()

class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
        "You died.  You kinda suck at this.",
         "Your mom would be proud...if she were smarter.",
         "Such a luser.",
         "I have a small puppy that's better at this."
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
        exit(1)

class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "you entered"

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "1":
            return 'death'

        elif action == "2":
            return 'death'

        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
            return 'central_corridor'

class Finished(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You won! Good job."
        return 'finished'

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished(),
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

What I hate about this code is that if the user misspell `action` the class start over again. I don't want to print everything again, I just want the user to be prompted with the `raw_input`.

I thought that this was enough:

```
class Actions(object):

    # Asks a command to the user
    def action(self, actions):
        self.actions = actions

        command = raw_input('> ')

        if command in self.actions.keys():
            return self.actions[command]

        elif command == 'HELP':
            print 'The available actions are:'
            for value in self.actions.keys():
                print ' * ', value
            self.action(self.actions)

        else:
            print 'Repeat please:'
            self.action(self.actions)

cmd = Actions()
```

With this module the user can digit what he wants until the action he digits is one of the actions in a dict.

When I run this module separately it works. If I type `print` instead of `return`, it will print the value.
However if I import this module everything will work but the return value:

```
class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    actions = {
        'quit': 'death' # I need that cmd.action() returns 'death'
    }

    def enter(self):
        print "you entered"

        cmd.action(CentralCorridor.actions)
```

The python console returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 77, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "main.py", line 24, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

It looks like it works only with this code (the code that I don't want to use):
    action = raw_input("> ")

```
if action == "1":
    return 'death'

elif action == "2":
    return 'death'

else:
    print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
    return 'central_corridor'
```

Can you please explain me what am I doing wrong and why it won't work or how to make it work?

Comment: seems that the variable `current_scene` is set to be `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you do not return the value from your recursive call in the Actions class, it should be:

```
class Actions(object):

    # Asks a command to the user
    def action(self, actions):
        self.actions = actions

        command = raw_input('> ')

        if command in self.actions.keys():
            return self.actions[command]

        elif command == 'HELP':
            print 'The available actions are:'
            for value in self.actions.keys():
                print ' * ', value
            return self.action(self.actions) # return recursive call

        else:
            print 'Repeat please:'
            return self.action(self.actions) # return here too

cmd = Actions()
```

Also you forgot to return the cmd.action call in CorridorScene:

```
class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    actions = {
        'quit': 'death' # I need that cmd.action() returns 'death'
    }

    def enter(self):
        print "you entered"

        return cmd.action(CentralCorridor.actions) # return here too
```

Comment: Still does not work! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 77, in <module>
    rooms_of_madness.play()
  File "main.py", line 24, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'

Comment: @dcdeiv then you also have an error with your current_scene being set to None inside of the `play` method. You will need to try and debug that code.

Comment: isn't it set to `a_map = Map('central_corridor')` at the end of the code?

Comment: @dcdeiv You also forgot a return when you call cmd.actions(). You need to return the cmd.action(CentralCorridor.actions) call in the CentralCorridor class.